# PostUpdate hook is not working, while doing batch update

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working with JPA/Hibernate.

I am doing bulk-update:

**Code Snippet:**

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManage entityManager;

   ...
private int update(StudentEntity studentEntity){
 CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaUpdate<StudentEntity > criteria = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(StudentEntity.class);
 Root<StudentEntity> root = criteria.form(StudentEntity.class)
 setFields(criteria, root, studentEntity)
 criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("studentId"), studentEntity.getStudentId()));
 return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).executeUpdate();
}

private setFields(CriteriaUpdate<StudentEntity> criteria,  Root<StudentEntity> root,StudentEntity  studentEntity){
 criteria.set(root.get("studentName"),studentEntity.getStudentName());

 ....
}
```

While executing the above code `@PostUpdate` hook is not getting invoked, why?

```
@PostUpdate
private update (StudentEntity studentEntity){
  System.out.println("@PostUpdate called.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the JPA specification (section 3.5.3):

> The `PreUpdate` and `PostUpdate` callbacks occur before and after the database update operations to entity data respectively.

I.e. these events only get triggered when using the entity lifecycle to load an entity, manipulate it and then flush the state to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so in your opinion what should I do now?

Comment: Obviously depends on what your goal is.

Comment: I want to keep the existing code and also want to invoke @PostUpdate callback method.

Comment: If you don't want to change your update code to use the JPA lifecycle but still want to call the @PostUpdate callback, you'll have to call the callback yourself. Seems obvious.
Of course the question is: why do you insist on using an approach that you just learned doesn't work?

Comment: Currently, we don't want to change the existing approach, if at all required. You have mentioned that I have to call the callback myself. How can I do that?

Comment: Use the criteria to load the entities and invoke the method. If you don't want to directly invoke the method you may use reflection to find methods with a given annotation.

Comment: I didn't get that. Could you please share a code snippet?

Comment: You would need to share more code about how you create your criteria, since you would need to extract the "where"-part of it in order to use it in a select query.

Comment: Okay, sure. I have updated the code. Could you please have a look?