# PostUpdate hook is not working, while doing batch update

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with JPA/Hibernate.

I am doing bulk-update:

**Code Snippet:**

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManage entityManager;

   ...
private int update(StudentEntity studentEntity){
 CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaUpdate<StudentEntity > criteria = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(StudentEntity.class);
 Root<StudentEntity> root = criteria.form(StudentEntity.class)
 setFields(criteria, root, studentEntity)
 criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("studentId"), studentEntity.getStudentId()));
 return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).executeUpdate();
}

private setFields(CriteriaUpdate<StudentEntity> criteria,  Root<StudentEntity> root,StudentEntity  studentEntity){
 criteria.set(root.get("studentName"),studentEntity.getStudentName());

 ....
}
```

While executing the above code `@PostUpdate` hook is not getting invoked, why?

```
@PostUpdate
private update (StudentEntity studentEntity){
  System.out.println("@PostUpdate called.");
}
```

Comment: Why are you deleting your question that already has an answer and posting a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61227657/66686

Comment: Got no workable solution, so thought of deleting.

Comment: You got a pretty decent answer based on the specification. What you didn't get a solution for was a question you asked in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that answer didn't solve my problem.

Comment: As @JensSchauder already said: executeUpdate does not trigger the PostUpdate. executeUpdate bypasses the EntityManger You cannot use entity listeners that way

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I understand that how can I use entity listeners?

Comment: You have to change your code to read the entity and then change it.